# Executing the TF model recurrently

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

In my research work, I need to process multiple inputs (let's say 1-20) by the same TensorFlow LSTM neural network model at a time and get corresponding outputs. The inputs  shapes are [1,50] dtype float32. I use Nvidia RTX3080 and the models are built
from scratch in TensorFlow 2.5.0 Functional API. For tests let's assume I've got always 10 inputs. As for now, I tried three cases:

**1. Single NN and recurrently sending single input:**
[Single input | single NN | single output (architecture pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTODT.jpg)

```
import sys
import os
from sys import platform
import numpy as np
import time
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"
NAME = "Cats-vs-dogs-64x2-CNN"
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(NAME))
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
devices = device_lib.list_local_devices()

example=[139.90614235043128,    139.1,  139.2,  139.3,  139.4,  139.5,  139.6,  139.7,  139.8,  
      139.9,    139.10, 139.11, 139.12, 139.13, 139.14, 139.15, 139.16, 139.17, 139.18, 
      139.19,   139.20, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    
      0.0,  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    52.23579347195013,  
      626.5563698366359,    41.93702299827743,  636.7379335603795,  57.39499094821983,  
      662.4703664367742,    221.61425047522275, 657.3963884100177,  216.48704029936889, 
      672.7126640217202,    152.36852662259034, 701.0]


try:
    print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
    gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
    if gpus:
        physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
        try:
            tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
        except:
            # Invalid device or cannot modify virtual devices once initialized.
            pass  

    model_name='1_1_1.h5'

    out=np.array([example for q in range(1)] )
    pkp = out.reshape([-1, 1,50]).astype("float32")

    #first time is longer
    with tf.device("GPU:0"):
      load_model2=tf.keras.models.load_model(model_name)
      y_=load_model2.predict(pkp)
    
    #show time
    for i in range(10):
      t=time.time()
      with tf.device("GPU:0"):
        for z in range(10): # each for one input
          y_=load_model2.predict(pkp)
        
      print('\nPrediction time for '+model_name+': '+str(time.time()-t))
 

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit(-1)
```

**2. Multi NN and sending multi inputs:**

[Multi inputs | multi NN | multi outputs (architecture pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvRyx.jpg)

```
...
    mmm='10_10_10'

    out=np.array([ret for q in range(1)] )
    pkp = out.reshape([-1, 1,50]).astype("float32")

    with tf.device("GPU:0"):
      load_model2=tf.keras.models.load_model(mmm+'.h5')
      y_=load_model2.predict(x={'0_INPUT':pkp,'1_INPUT':pkp,'2_INPUT':pkp,'3_INPUT':pkp,'4_INPUT':pkp,
                                '5_INPUT':pkp,'6_INPUT':pkp,'7_INPUT':pkp,'8_INPUT':pkp,'9_INPUT':pkp})
        
    for i in range(10):
      t=time.time()
      with tf.device("GPU:0"):
        y_=load_model2.predict(x={'0_INPUT':pkp,'1_INPUT':pkp,'2_INPUT':pkp,'3_INPUT':pkp,'4_INPUT':pkp,
                                  '5_INPUT':pkp,'6_INPUT':pkp,'7_INPUT':pkp,'8_INPUT':pkp,'9_INPUT':pkp})
        
      print('\nPrediction time for '+mmm+':'+str(time.time()-t))
...
```

**3. Multi NN and sending single input:**

[Single input | multi NN | single output (architecture pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVBLk.jpg)

```
    mmm='1_10_1'
 
    out=np.array([ret for q in range(10)] )
    pkp = out.reshape([-1, 10,50]).astype("float32")

    with tf.device("GPU:0"):
      load_model2=tf.keras.models.load_model(mmm+'.h5')
      y_=load_model2.predict(pkp)
        
    for i in range(10):
      t=time.time()
      with tf.device("GPU:0"):
        y_=load_model2.predict(pkp)
        
      print('\nPrediction time for '+mmm+':'+str(time.time()-t))
```

Each case executes properly, but too slow. In each case, the time to process 10 inputs takes ap. 13 seconds.

My goal is to achieve min. 10 FPS with 20 inputs. Is there any other way to speed up processing time?